Match string but not if it's preceded by a different word
I want a regex to match "email" but not "verify email".
How can I do this?
I've tried the following but no luck:
[^(verify)] email


Use a negative look behind:
(?<!verify )email

See live demo.

Not all regex engines support lookbehinds.  Also, your pattern, as written, would also rule out unverify email, which maybe should be a match.  If so, you should have a word boundary before verify.

@Tim unverify email should be excluded, because OP does not specify that "verify" must be a word.
